# where are the source and javadoc jars for a maven repo stored in netbeans ide?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, javadoc

I right clicked on dependency JAR files in a netbeans maven project and tried downloading source and javadoc, this was done successfully by Netbeans, however now I dont see a way to access the source JAR and javadoc JAR.

Please let me know how to obtain the source and javadoc jars, esp where they are being stored by the IDE currently.

Arvind.

Comment: You could put a search in your C: drive for *.extension or the name of the jar you downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in `~/.m2/repository` on *nix or `C:\Documents and Settings\$USERNAME\.m2\repository` in Windows